# Creating multiple SFTP users who use different SSH keys to connect to the same chrooted directory?

Tags: ssh, ftp, sftp, filezilla, chroot

I have an Ubuntu-powered server, which - among other things - acts as file storage/hosting (powered by nginx), so that if a file is put in `/var/www/files.ourcompany.com/file.txt`, it is publicly available at `http://files.ourcompany.com/file.txt`.

I want to restrict ability to the server to three specific users:

- User A is the overall sudo-enabled user who has SSH and SFTP access to everything. He is authorized by his SSH key(s) in `/home/userA/.ssh/authorized_keys`. Essentially this is the replacement for root.
- User B is a normal user that uses FileZilla. He cannot use SSH, only SFTP, and can only see `/var/www/files.ourcompany.com` when he logs in. He is authorized via SSH key that is placed in `/etc/ssh/authorized_keys/userB` (as described [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SFTP_chroot#Fixing_path_for_authorized_keys))
- User C is exactly like User B, except he has his SSH key in `/etc/ssh/authorized_keys/userC` instead

Is the above possible using `chroot` or something similar? User A already has all the permissions he needs, but I am unsure of how to create the two normal users who should both be chrooted to the same folder (with upload/download capabilities) - `/var/www/files.ourcompany.com` - so that when they sign on via FileZilla they are immediately placed in that folder. I'm also scared of accidentally breaking the existing nginx setup due to rights issues...

Comment: You can have multiple keys in an authorised_keys file - and have users log in as commonusername@destip - with each one using their own key. This may make it harder to track who actually logged in though.

Comment: @davidgo I know, but that is exactly what I want to avoid. Since we'll end up having 5-10 users with SFTP access to the same file storage I want the logs to clearly show who comes and goes

Comment: Surely the answer would just be to up the logging?  Also,  you could upload files with 664 / 775 perms and have all the users in a group - and structure the file server so that you have /data/home/user and /data/www - and chroot them to /data

Comment: Without knowing too much about sftp or ftps - I posit you could set up an ftps server using, for example, pureftp and have logging on a per user basis, with a shared directory and appropriate perms.